# Filter string by using exact substring

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

i need to search and fetch objects from CoreData based on a search key.
My core data object contains a string property called `names`. My requirement is as like follows

```
managedObject1.names = "James,James Willson,Willson James,James Camaroon"
managedObject2.names = "James Willson,James,Willson James,James Camaroon"
managedObject3.names = "James Camaroon,James Willson,Willson James,James"
managedObject4.names = "James Willson,Willson James,James Camaroon"
```

When user search a key with 'James', i want only managedObject1, managedObject2 and managedObject3.

I tried `NSPredicate(format: "names contains[d] %@", name)` but it returning managedObject4 too.

How to write the predicate for this?

Comment: Yeah! because it too have `James` as a substring. Predicates always return that object. So why you don't need object 4.

Comment: You should probably get all the managed objects and use the swift `filter` method. It's more flexible and faster.

Comment: @Sweeper: Filtering via NSPredicate in the fetch request is done on the SQlite level and has the advantage of loading only the matching objects into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a predicate with a regular expression pattern which 
matches the name enclosed by commas:

```
let name = "James"
let pattern = "(.*,)?\(NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: name))(,.*)?"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name MATCHES %@", pattern)
```

(A better model would be to have a to-many relationship with a "Name" entity instead of a single string containing comma-separated names.)

Comment: I +1 the model change. It should be better and easier to search/filter afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your requirements properly, you want to return only those objects that have James as a name without any first name or last name?

In that case you can have a condition like this

```
let names = "James Willson,Willson James,James Camaroon"
let searchedString = "James"
let searchedStringCount = searchedString.characters.count

let endIndex = names.index(names.startIndex, offsetBy: searchedStringCount + 1)
let startIndex = names.index(names.endIndex, offsetBy: -(searchedStringCount + 1))

let startString = names.substring(to: endIndex) // prints "James "
let endString = names.substring(from: startIndex) // prints "maroon"

let shouldBeReturned = startString == "\(searchedString)," || endString == ",\(searchedString)" || names.contains(",\(searchedString),") // prints false
```

Such a condition takes into account the fact that the name can be at the beginning (no coma in front of it) or at the end (no comma after it)